# Kotlin with Map ( Marker Not showing)

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

Hello I'm trying to implements `Google Maps` in kotlin, but in these code my `getMapAsync`is not getting called, the maps shows perfectly but the marker doesn't show up

```
    var mapFragment : SupportMapFragment?=null
    mapFragment= fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync { 
        val sydney = LatLng(22.30, 73.20)
        mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))


        Toast.makeText(activity,"dfgdg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
```

Comment: `mapFragment` is probably null, which means that the `fragmentManager` can't find it. Did you initialize the `SupportMapFragment` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Actually the map is displaying on screen but marker is not addded

Comment: Can you show your layout XML? Or do you call `SupportMapFragment()` (the constructor) somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using the wrong map instance.
2. Sydney lat lng are `-33.8479731,150.6517908`

> ```
> mapFragment?.getMapAsync { 
>
>     map ->  // <- this is the map that you got async not mMap            
>         val sydney = LatLng(-33.8479731, 150.6517908)
>         map.addMarker(...
>         map.moveCamera(...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try With This

```
val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sydney")    
mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)  
mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 16f))
```